# What counts as "private Affairs" for a S2 Visa in China

Tags: visas, china

As stated [here](http://mt.chineseembassy.org/eng/lsfw/qzzl/t1537367.htm) the S2 Visa is granted for the purpose of either

- visiting family members for a short period

or

- private affairs

I was wondering what counts as private affairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [TravelChinaGuide](https://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/private-visit.htm):

> Chinese private visit visa, more familiar to foreigners as S visa or
>   sometimes as the dependant visa, is issued to family members of
>   foreigners who reside in China for work or study or to those who
>   intend to go to China for **private affairs such as marriage, lawsuit,
>   heritage, adoption, and medical treatment**. It is further classified
>   into S1 visa and S2 visa. The former is for a longer stay duration of
>   more than 180 days, while the latter is for a stay duration not
>   exceeding 180 days.